# FCM send silent notification, if it's not delivered, send notification containing message title and body

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

if application is not running(force-quit by user) silent notification is never delivered, i wish to, if application is force-quit send normal notification(not-silent).

for sending silent notification my payload structure is

```
{  
   "data" : {
            "collapse_key" : "list_updated", 
            "job_type" : "updated"
            },
   "notification":{
      "content_available": true
   },
   "to":"eireXdn7hJw:APA91bHb_NKWC-qAjv-IplXVPAFJbfqCFnvOgVVKTT5j7zdL4iEC9assdmeyIcEZOEv0krSBcukN9bYqsmUSSCEUDXuJ4LzVYzhuIo6o_PPjWw3DvFoJCHFVb9GkNdulEAcvmj03QGP0I9tx"
}
```

payload is working fine for silent notification, i do receive notification when app is running in foreground or background. as far as i know, if application is running in foreground(Active) FCM send direct message, not using APNS, so there is some kind of mechanisms FCM know application running state.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Are you saying you wish to detect if the app has been force-quit by the user and, if so, send a visible notification instead of a silent one?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman yes